# Like-Button problems

Tags: wordpress, button, facebook-like

my name is Sebastian and i have massive problems with my like button on www.starsontv.com

Everything should be ok said this link

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.starsontv.com%2F2012%2F10%2F06%2Fx-factor-2012-wer-schafft-es-noch-ins-juryhaus%2Fartikel-0014315%2F

But you can´t use the like button. What is the problem? How can i solve this problem?

This problems is there since yesterday.

I have no idea and i didn´t change my website.

Can anyone help me, please?

Thank you very much....

Greetings from germany
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the like button without a problem. What happens that prevents you from using it?